# Sharepoint Framework cant find module

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint

I had a project which used youtube-api-search in it. it works there fine.

I have created a sharepoint framework template with yeoman "yo @microsoft/sharepoint" and installed youtube api package as I did in previous project. but when I run this project I encounter an error like below;
[image]

> Cannot find module 'youtube-api-search'

as I said its working in other react project do i need something specially to make it work here ?
I installed api via "npm i youtube-api-search --save-dev" command
here main component content;

```
        import * as React from 'react';
        import { css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
        import styles from './Announcements.module.scss';
        import { IAnnouncementsProps } from './IAnnouncementsProps';
        //I have added only these 2 lines to default code
        import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
        const YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCI9gcceui5zcQDAEwbyv...";



    export default class Announcements extends React.Component<IAnnouncementsProps, void> {

      public render(): React.ReactElement<IAnnouncementsProps> {
        return (
         ...
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can import modules in three methods

FIRST::Using Config-->config.json and change

```
 "externals": {
    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js",
    "OwlCarousel":{
      "path":"./node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.min.js",
      "globalName":"OwlCarousel"
    },
    "Slider":{"path":"./node_modules/react-slick/lib/slider.js",
    "globalName":"Sliders"}
  },
```

SECOND:: npm install @types/youtube-api-search --save

THIRD ::

```
 `npm install typings` 

`typings install dt~youtube-api-search -global --save`
```

sometimes dt~ is neccessary sometimes it is not necessaary